# Hyperparam search on huggingface with optuna fails with wandb error

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, hyperparameters, optuna

I'm using this simple script, using the example blog post. However, it fails because of `wandb`. It was of no use to make `wandb` OFFLINE as well.

```
from datasets import load_dataset, load_metric
from transformers import (AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer,
                          Trainer, TrainingArguments)
import wandb


wandb.init()

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
dataset = load_dataset('glue', 'mrpc')
metric = load_metric('glue', 'mrpc')

def encode(examples):
    outputs = tokenizer(
        examples['sentence1'], examples['sentence2'], truncation=True)
    return outputs

encoded_dataset = dataset.map(encode, batched=True)

def model_init():
    return AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
        'distilbert-base-uncased', return_dict=True)

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    predictions, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = predictions.argmax(axis=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)

# Evaluate during training and a bit more often
# than the default to be able to prune bad trials early.
# Disabling tqdm is a matter of preference.
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    "test", eval_steps=500, disable_tqdm=True,
    evaluation_strategy='steps',)

trainer = Trainer(
    args=training_args,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    train_dataset=encoded_dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=encoded_dataset["validation"],
    model_init=model_init,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

def my_hp_space(trial):
    return {
        "learning_rate": trial.suggest_float("learning_rate", 1e-4, 1e-2, log=True),
        "weight_decay": trial.suggest_float("weight_decay", 0.1, 0.3),
        "num_train_epochs": trial.suggest_int("num_train_epochs", 5, 10),
        "seed": trial.suggest_int("seed", 20, 40),
        "per_device_train_batch_size": trial.suggest_categorical("per_device_train_batch_size", [32, 64]),
    }


trainer.hyperparameter_search(
    direction="maximize",
    backend="optuna",
    n_trials=10,
    hp_space=my_hp_space
)
```

`Trail 0` finishes successfully, but next `Trail 1` crashes with following error:

```
  File "/home/user123/anaconda3/envs/iza/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/integrations.py", line 138, in _objective
    trainer.train(resume_from_checkpoint=checkpoint, trial=trial)
  File "/home/user123/anaconda3/envs/iza/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1376, in train
    self.log(metrics)
  File "/home/user123/anaconda3/envs/iza/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1688, in log
    self.control = self.callback_handler.on_log(self.args, self.state, self.control, logs)
  File "/home/user123/anaconda3/envs/iza/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer_callback.py", line 371, in on_log
    return self.call_event("on_log", args, state, control, logs=logs)
  File "/home/user123/anaconda3/envs/iza/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer_callback.py", line 378, in call_event
    result = getattr(callback, event)(
  File "/home/user123/anaconda3/envs/iza/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/integrations.py", line 754, in on_log
    self._wandb.log({**logs, "train/global_step": state.global_step})
  File "/home/user123/anaconda3/envs/iza/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wandb/sdk/lib/preinit.py", line 38, in preinit_wrapper
    raise wandb.Error("You must call wandb.init() before {}()".format(name))
wandb.errors.Error: You must call wandb.init() before wandb.log()
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more description where `wandb.log`, `wandb.sweep`, `wandb.agent` is being used?

Comment: There is nothing else apart from the above code. There's a`wandb.init()` at the start and that's it.

Comment: Unless you use ```wandb.log```, you can't see the runs on the dashboard. See https://github.com/wandb/examples/blob/master/examples/pytorch/pytorch-cnn-fashion/train.py for example.

Comment: I don't want to see anything on dashboard. The problem is the above code doesn't run because of wandb error.

Comment: Ran your code, it works fine for me. Not sure why it doesn't work for you. Make sure you are already logged using `wandb login` and you are using the latest versions. You can then also try `wandb init` from CLI instead of the script.

Comment: Could it be an environment issue then?

Comment: might be `wandb` version issue. Looks like PR solved it https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/pull/1373

Comment: I tried many ways in env variables. Can you tell ur `transformers` and `wandb` version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check running the code on the latest versions of wandb and transformers. Works fine for me with `wandb 0.11.0` and `transformers 4.9.0`

Comment: Thank you. It was version issue.